# Reading cookies

Tags: php, cookies

When I do:

`print_r($_COOKIE[@PATH]);`

It returns a nice array:

> Array ( ['threads'] => Array ( [12] => Array ( [50] => 1317830223 [1]
>   => 1317785487 [14] => 1317497737 [7] => 1317488004 [9] => 1317485889
>   [6] => 1317294825 [5] => 1317289974 [4] => 1317288063 ) ) )

But when I do:

`print_r($_COOKIE[@PATH]['threads']);`

It doesn't print anything... `var_dump` is also returning NULL.

Whats wrong with that? First print is saying that there is an array like this, but when I try to catch it, script returning null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the looks of your array output, your cookie array contains a key named `'threads'`, not `threads`.  Those quotes are part of the key name, so somewhere you are adding extraneous quotes to the key.

Try `print_r($_COOKIE[@PATH]["'threads'"]);` to see what I mean.